# strip leading zeros in awk program

Tags: awk

So I'm pretty lost as I missed a week and am playing catch up, but I'm to write an awk program to tell the difference, in days, between two dates.

I'm more or less done with it, however it doesn't like it if the user inputs 01/01/YYYY when doing my data validation. I pull the 3 fields out of the arg then pass them to a function to validate.

the part that's giving me trouble is, in my validation:

```
if ( day > Days[month] ){
invalid stuff here
}
```

where `Days[]` is an array holding [1]=31, [2]=28 (or 29 if leap) etc.

It hits true because Days[01] is not defined. I could go around it by defining a [01] as the same as [1] I suppose but I'd rather something more elegant.

How can I strip the leading zeros, within the awk program, of the variable month? Everything I've found is for use in a shell script and invokes awk, but that doesn't really help me.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need this, assuming your variable is called `month`:

```
gsub ("^0*", "", month);
```

The `^` is the start anchor and `0*` means zero or more `0` characters. So this effectively removes all `0` characters at the start of the variable.

By way of example (which also shows a way to do it to the *middle* number as well, before splitting the date apart, see the second `gsub` for that):

```
pax> echo '1/1/2013
03/12/2014
02/02/1965' | awk '{gsub ("^0*", "", $0); gsub ("/0*", "/", $0); print}'

1/1/2013
3/12/2014
2/2/1965
```

Comment: I'm still wrapping my head around regex, but is that essentially saying "start at the beginning, match 0 followed by anything else, replace only the exact match with nothing"?

Either way it works exactly as I wanted. Thanks so much.

Comment: @Dirgon, close but not quite. `*` doesn't mean anything, it means 0 or more of the preceding "thing". In other words, `^0*` will match any number of 0's (including none) at the start of the string.

Comment: @MadCalm: if you read the question, the range of input values is `1, 2, …, 12`, there *is* no possibility of month number `0`. Were it a more generalised question (one that wanted to handle `0`), I would have catered for that.

Answer (score 11):

Another option:

```
$ echo 01234 | awk '{x=$0+0;print x}'
1234
```

Comment: +1 coercing to a numeric value by adding 0 is the most correct way to do this in awk.

Comment: This is very, very neat

Comment: just do `awk '($!_+=_)_'` it's cleaner

Answer (score 2):

I tried the answer suggested by @paxdiablo. It ended up stripping the non-leading zeros as well.

```
$ echo '20/02/1965' | awk '{gsub ("^0*", "", $0); gsub ("/0*", "/", $0); print}'
2/2/1965
```

Using `sub` instead `gsub` worked fine for me.

```
$ echo '20/02/1965' | awk '{sub ("^0*", "", $0); sub ("/0*", "/", $0); print}' 
20/2/1965
```

Answer (score 0):

Latest contribution somewhat shortened.

```
echo '20/02/1965' | awk '{sub ("/0", "/", $0)}1'
20/2/1965
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm sorry. My answer is not about awk, and it is about bash itself. So please don't give a minus for my comment)

```
echo -e "00000000" | sed -r 's/^[0]*$/0/g' | sed -r 's/^0[0]+//g'
```

Or perform integer calculations with (( )) notations

```
echo $((0000))
```

Comment: why not give an example in Perl, agol, and other unrelated languages as well? OP is clearly writing a programme in awk…

Comment: I don't know Perl, and It seems to me that me Perl is more far away for this question. Usually sed/awk are used together. So I'll think this info can be usefull